# Filling two angular $scope variables with data

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, angular.js

I'm unsure about how to simplify this method properly. The method is basically responsible to allocate data.

The response object is a collection of objects. Each object contains an attribute called `order` and i have to distinguish between visible and invisible elements. Visible elements are represented by positive integers, invisible elements by a negative integers.

Also it is possible to overwrite the default state if the URL contains an parameter (hidden) with a list of hidden element ids. `?hidden=23,432,3,123`

`_hasParam()` returns `boolean`

`_getParam()` returns `string` (separated by comma [23,432,3,123])

`contains()` returns `boolean`

```
prepare: function (response) {

    var visible = [];
    var invisible = [];

    if (_hasParam('hidden')) {

        var hidden = _getParam('hidden').split(',');

        angular.forEach(response, function (item) {
            if (hidden.contains(item.id)) {
                invisible.push(item);
            } else {
                visible.push(item);
            }
        });

    } else {

        angular.forEach(response, function (item) {
            if (item.order === -1) {
                invisible.push(item);
            } else {
                visible.push(item);
            }
        });

    }

    $rootScope.visible = visible;
    $rootScope.invisible = invisible;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that stands out a bit is the fact that you do 2 very similar `angular.forEach()` calls. You could extract these functions out and do only 1 call. I would also make `-1` a named constant. I would also declare all variables on top.

What you could consider, but I don't advise it, since it reeks too much of CodeGolf, is to simplify the 2 if statements to 1 single `push()` call

```
(hidden.contains(item.id)? invisible : visible).push( item );
```

This piece of code extracts the filter functions and applies my other suggestions:

```
prepare: function (response) {

    var visible = [],
        invisible = [],
        HIDE = -1,
        hidden, filter;

    if (_hasParam('hidden')) {
        hidden = _getParam('hidden').split(',');
        /* Hide based on the hidden parameter */
        filter = function (item) {
            if (hidden.contains(item.id)) {
                invisible.push(item);
            } else {
                visible.push(item);
            }
        }
    } else {
        filter = function (item) {
        /* Hide based on the order of the item */
            if (item.order === HIDE) {
                invisible.push(item);
            } else {
                visible.push(item);
            }
        }    
    }

    angular.forEach(response, filter);
    $rootScope.visible = visible;
    $rootScope.invisible = invisible;
}
```